# Map with a multi-valued key?

Tags: java, optimization

I have created an implementation in Java of `Policy` objects that apply to a particular `Namespace`.

They are stored in a `Map<Namespace,List<Policy>>` structure so I can easily retrieve the policies for a particular namespace by calling `.containsKey()` and `.get()` on the Map. For this I have overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` according to JVM rules. Worked fine.

Now the requirements are changing, and a `Namespace` suddenly consists of a list of values where the equality rule is *"one of the values must match"*. In other words, if one of the values stored in `Namespace A` matches one of the values stored in `Namespace B` they are 'equal'.

Obviously overriding `hashCode()` does not work anymore since I do not know which value's code to represent.

How can I best adapt my design to the new equality rule? Should I still be using a `Map` or is there a pattern which fits my case?

Answer (score 1):

If you allowed to use libraries, maybe apache `MultiKeyMap` can be helpful.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try it. First glance is hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly you need something like this:

```
class Key {
    Set values;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object key2) {
        // Returns true if one of the values of this key matches one of the values of key2
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. However `HashMap` calls the `hashCode()` method on my keys - what will happen if all keys return *1* to that call? Isn't that against JVM rules?